# Декодирование строки с символами \u0431 C#

Tags: c#

Есть строка вида

```
string s ="\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440."
```

Если я её вставляю в какой-нибудь онлайн сервис, то оно успешно декодируется как

```
быть 12 цифр.
```

И онлайн сервис показывает разные кодировки, автоматические им подобранные. Например, что исходный текст был unicode, а после перевода - UTF8

Ок, пишем тоже самое на С#

```
            string substring ="\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440."
            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

            // Convert the string into a byte array.
            byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(substring);

            // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, utf8, unicodeBytes);

            // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
            char[] utf8Chars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length)];
            utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0);
            string utf8String = new string(utf8Chars);
            Console.WriteLine(utf8string);
```

И на выходе получаем точно такой же

```
\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440.
```

Как я понимаю, я неправильно понял саму суть кодировки - кодировка кодирует байты, а строка изначально уже закодирована чем то внутренним в C#, возможно, тем же UTF8, поэтому он и не пытается перекодировать символы \u0431 и остальные в кириллицу, а просто считает что строка и так уже в UTF8.

Вопрос - как скормить декодеру эти самые escape-последовательности, означающие какие то киррилическим символы, чтобы в итоге он выдал мне то же самое, что и онлайн сервисы?

По запросу комментаторов вывел utf8chars, это массив чаров, поэтому вывел через foreach

вывод

\

u

0

4

4

с

1

2

Комментарий после верного ответа.

ответ дан 32 минуты назад

@vp_arth

Regex.Unescape помог. Действительно, неудобно получилось - я хотел сократить вопрос, поэтому написал строку заранее. Но на самом деле я получаю эту строку из веб реквеста, и при её выводе получаю недекодированные символы. Если взять символы снова и просто забить их в строку - всё выводится корректно. Видимо, строка как раз и делает Regex.Unescape в первый раз, поэтому повторно выводит корректно

Comment: А вы пробовали выводить substring? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ofGlZ4

Comment: Или вы имели в виду `"\\u0431"`?

Comment: @AK Вывел, все в основном посте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В такой строке уже декодированные символы:

```
Console.WriteLine("\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440."); 
// быть 12 цифр.
```

А тут сырая строка со слешами, их можно, например, заменить вручную:

```
string s = @"\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440."; 
Console.WriteLine(s);
// \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440.

Regex  rx = new Regex( @"\\u([0-9a-f]{4})");
s = rx.Replace(s, match => ((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString() );
Console.WriteLine(s);
// быть 12 цифр.
```

Или проще:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(@"\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c 12 \u0446\u0438\u0444\u0440."));
// быть 12 цифр.
```

Comment: Regex.Unescape помог.  Действительно, неудобно получилось - я хотел сократить вопрос, поэтому написал строку заранее. Но на самом деле я получаю эту строку из веб реквеста, и при её выводе получаю недекодированные символы. 
Если взять символы снова и просто забить их в строку - всё выводится корректно. Видимо, строка как раз и делает Regex.Unescape в первый раз, поэтому повторно выводит корректно.